# Etiqueta duplicada h1

Tags: html

hola buenas tengo una etiqueta h1 duplicacada  por que tengo un editor en mi wordpress que se llama tatsu de el tema oshine que tengo que hacer varias versiones para tablets ordenadores moviles  el texto lo tengo asi

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">marcos ocio</span></h1>
```

https://marcosocio.com/

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Marcos, explica cual es el error, y que te refieres con lo de la h1 duplicada

Comment: Puedes tener tantos `<h1>` como quieras, no hay ningún problema con tener varios.

Answer (score 0):

aqui me aparece el error de la etiquta duplicada lo unico que no se es que codigo entero tengo que pasar para analizarlo bien [image: error que aparece en bing]
[image: de una extension seo para mozilla]

Comment: Esto va como edicion a la publicacion, no como respuesta. Y de donde sacas que esos son errores ??

Answer (score 0):

Es preferible que edites la pregunta, en vez de publicar una respuesta sólo para añadir detalles a la misma.

Dicho esto, como ya han comentado en la pregunta, tener varias etiquetas `<h1>` es HTML válido. Le estás dando demasiada importancia a una sugerencia que a fin de cuentas es solo eso: Una sugerencia.

https://searchengineland.com/multiple-h1s-wont-get-in-the-way-of-your-seo-google-says-322909

Según este articulo, ni siquiera afectará a tu SEO, si eso es lo que te preocupa.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo mantener únicamente una etiqueta . Puedes entrar a editar la plantilla de tu Wordpress para mantener los títulos en H1 y lo demás en H2, H3, etc.

Revisa un poco sobre SEO On Page para seguir mejorando las buenas prácticas SEO.